# how to use fiba tape for drywall patch?

Tags: drywall

This fiba tape stuff protrudes from my drywall. Are you supposed to sand it? I don't see the use of it for patching a hole if it's thicker than my texture. Looks bad.

[http://www.lowes.com/pd/FibaTape-300-ft-Self-Adhesive-Joint-Tape/50183377?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-*-Paint-*-WallRepair-_-50183377:FibaTape&CAWELAID=&kpid=50183377&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=102](http://www.lowes.com/pd/FibaTape-300-ft-Self-Adhesive-Joint-Tape/50183377?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-Paint-_-WallRepair-_-50183377:FibaTape&CAWELAID=&kpid=50183377&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=102)

Or is this user error?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a putty knife, and some [joint compound](http://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-12-lb-Premixed-Finishing-Drywall-Joint-Compound/3017362) to apply over the top of it; the mesh provides some structure over the hole, you build it up just a little higher than the undamaged area, and feather it smooth; when you sand it, you will be sanding the compound, not the mesh. If you are careful applying the compound, very little sanding should be needed.